# 404 error page redirect back to home page

Tags: php, statements

I have a website www.thewritedesign.co.uk. My site is based on includes. My navigation at the top of the site all use achor links and the site is all one page. I have an error page, so when you type www.thewritedesign.co.uk/euskdfzxcahsz, the remaining /euskdfzxcahsz stays in the URL and my navigation links do not work when you land on my error page because they have #services #about etc as the link.

I have wrote an if statement for my other page "Terrms and Conditions" if you land on /terms-and-conditions that if you use the navigation links at the top of that page, you can get back on track so the links are now /index#services /index#about etc.

My question is. If you land on www.thewritedesign.co.uk/euskdfzxcahsz, is there an if statement I can use to say whatever page you land on which doesn't exist, go back to /index#services /index#about

Thanks

Comment: You could simply name the links `/#service` etc. You don't need the `index` part. Then it will work on all pages and the URL will look nice and clean. If that doesn't solve your issue, then I'm not really sure what you're asking.

Comment: You could handle the logic through the htaccess file. I believe that would be the easiest. Look into RewriteEngine and 404 handling through the htaccess file. You can simply make your index page your 404 page, which is what you want I guess?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I changed all of my links to /# and every single page now works and the URL does look much neater. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

One of the better ways (in my opinion) is to let the *htaccess* file handle this issue for you.

The *htaccess* file has a RewriteEngine that allows you to do a lot of things in terms of URL handling. What's most interesting for you, would be the *ErrorDocument 404* handling.

A 404 error is basically a *"dead link"*, meaning that whatever destination the user is trying to arrive at, doesn't exist. You can then choose to redirect the user through an error handling in the htaccess file.

Example:

```
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.yoursite.com/index.php#services
```

Change the URL in the example to fit your needs.